# How to prevent users from logging in from multiple devices using FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, jwt, fastapi

Can we restrict users signing in from multiple devices using JWT token or do we need to go for session-based authentication?

Which way is the best to restrict the user?

Have Implemented JWT for Authentication in FastAPI.

```
def __init__(self,auto_Error: bool = True):
    super(jwtBearer,self).__init__(auto_error=auto_Error)

async def __call__(self,request:Request):
    credentials : HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = await super(jwtBearer,self).__call__(request)
    if credentials:
        if not credentials.scheme == "Bearer":
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403,details="Invalid or Expired Token!")
        return credentials.credentials
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403,details="Invalid or Expired Token!")

def verify_jwt(self,jwttoken: str):
    isTokenValid : bool = False
    payload = decodejwt(jwttoken)
    if payload:
        isTokenValid = True
    return isTokenValid
```